# Cloudflare redirect to another URL when the first URL destination returned error

Tags: cloudflare

I'm setting up rules for CloudFlare for my Google Cloud Storage but I'm getting stuck now. I want to know if it is possible to redirect to another URL when google cloud storage return error such as 404 Not Found.

As I do now, I have some URL point to my Google Cloud Storage URL. 
Then if the data in Google Cloud Storage does not exist, it would return some error to the client when they request to the URL. That is not what I want.

My Expected Result is that my URL could be able to redirect to another URL when the first URL returned error. (So that I can show some default data to them actually)

I already tried Cloudflare worker. It does work but I don't really want to use this solution yet because of budget problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this by setting default file from Google Cloud Storage itself so no need to set page rules in Cloudflare.